# How to see if Chrome manipulates HTML by itself?

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom, browser, developer-tools

If you forget to close a HTML-Tag, Chrome will validate your code and try to fix problems like this.

I had a major problem because I forgot a closing Form-Tag, and instead of closing it correctly, Chrome deleted a following form, not the inputs, simply the Form-Tags.

When I looked at the Source Code itself, the Form-Tag was there, but not in the Elements-Tab in the console.

So at first, I thought it must have something to do with some JS deleting this DOM-Node and set a DOM-Breakpoint to find the script.

To cut a long story short, it took me hours to find out, that no JS deleted my form, but Chrome itself thought: There is a missing  so I delete some other  to fix that...

Is there any possibilty to see if Chrome automatically changes your DOM?

Thank You!

Comment: Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).. It will easily point you to such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The browser Engine does indeed. They use string replace methods, although it happens internally.

```
<div>
</div>> // mistake
<div> //missing end tag
<div></div>
  --------------------------------------------------- 

Methods 

file=file.stringreplace('>>', '>') 

an uneven count will add the missing div just after the next beginning div and conditionally if the missing is not found by the end of the file:
  file=file.stringreplace('
  <div>', '</div>
  <div>')
```

The Parsing Engine after the missing and broken tags are repaired then parses the file and can then with a positive count set the screens GUI widgets by opening and closing tags as GUI Frames. It does this by adding tokens delimiters to the actual div tags making them easily distinguished from each other.

```
<div1s>
</div1e>
<div1s>//section columns
  <div2s></div2e>
  <div2s></div2e>
  <div2s></div2e>
</div1e>
<div1s>Footer</div1e>
-----------------------------------------------------
The GUI Frame Tokens
for each "<dive1>"{

FrameCreate(CSS--ATTRIBUTES FROM ASSOCIATIVE ARRAYS--)
//the GUI Frame Widgets VERTICAL SECTIONS
}
//Next it finds the nested divs2 and embeds these into the thir parents above but with embedded Text Widgets also.
FrameTextBoxCreate(--CSS MATED ATTRIBUTES RULES--)
div3 etc------and so on.
```

In fact it is in the WebView GUI Widget Sets in its customized Mosaic Canvas Widget Sets in Chrome would be where they are repaired.

Comment: So is there a possibility to see the repaired tags in the "WebView GUI Widget Sets in its customized Mosaic Canvas Widget Sets" in Chrome WITHOUT studying Browser Mechanics in Oxford or some similar educational journey?

Comment: it happens internally, so it is built into Chrome. Like Microsoft, Google encrypts their code so it is confusing. instead of using a variable like `setWindowSize`, they would use `1rjndshds2`. makes no sense at all.

Comment: In short I do not think so.